# How to edit row in datagrid after getting some validation errors in any one of the cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using DataGrid to show/edit data. I want to allow user to edit multiple rows though some of them may have validation errors. Right now if some row has validation errors I cannot edit other rows. I saw a solution where I need to use reflection to get some properties of the DataGrid. Is there a better, cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can customize you `datagrid` and override its `OnCanExecuteBeginEdit` event like this:

```
protected override void OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hasCellValidationError = false;
        var hasRowValidationError = false;
        const BindingFlags bindingFlags =
            BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        //Current cell
        var cellErrorInfo = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasCellValidationError", bindingFlags);
        //Grid row
        var rowErrorInfo = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("HasRowValidationError", bindingFlags);
        if (cellErrorInfo != null) hasCellValidationError = (bool) cellErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        if (rowErrorInfo != null) hasRowValidationError = (bool) rowErrorInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        base.OnCanExecuteBeginEdit(e);
        if ((!e.CanExecute && hasCellValidationError) || (!e.CanExecute && hasRowValidationError))
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
 }
```

It checks if the `datagrid` has validation errors then set its `e.CanExecute = true`,so you can type in another cells.

Comment: Yes, it works! However, UI logic is still buggy. E.g. if my datagrid has `CanUserAddRows="True"`. Here are steps: enter invalid value into empty row for adding new items, press Enter, go to some previously existing row, enter invalid value, press Enter, press Escape, enter valid value in recently added row, press Enter. Fix the error in the previously existing row. Doing so I get all valid rows and no empty row for adding new items.

Answer (score 0):

Add CellEditEnding property to datagrid

```html
CellEditEnding="DataGridCellEditEnding"
```

Implement the method

```html
private void DataGridCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```